# Dividir el ancho de la pantalla en dos contenedores

Tags: html, css

Tengo dos divs, uno es un sidebar y el otro un container. Quiero dividir la totalidad del ancho en estos dos (.sidebar 20%, .container 80%), pero no sé que sea lo que esté fallando porque no ocupan el ancho al 100%.

Estoy usando el Framework **Simple Grid**.

Este es mi código:

```css
/**
    *** SIMPLE GRID
    *** (C) ZACH COLE 2016
    **/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i');

/* UNIVERSAL */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}


/* ROOT FONT STYLES */

* {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #333447;
  line-height: 1.5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* TYPOGRAPHY */

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.375rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.font-light {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.font-regular {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.font-heavy {
  font-weight: 700;
}


/* POSITIONING */

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.justify {
  text-align: justify;
}


/* ==== GRID SYSTEM ==== */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.row [class^="col"] {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5rem 2%;
  min-height: 0.125rem;
}

.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4,
.col-5,
.col-6,
.col-7,
.col-8,
.col-9,
.col-10,
.col-11,
.col-12 {
  width: 96%;
}

.col-1-sm {
  width: 4.33%;
}

.col-2-sm {
  width: 12.66%;
}

.col-3-sm {
  width: 21%;
}

.col-4-sm {
  width: 29.33%;
}

.col-5-sm {
  width: 37.66%;
}

.col-6-sm {
  width: 46%;
}

.col-7-sm {
  width: 54.33%;
}

.col-8-sm {
  width: 62.66%;
}

.col-9-sm {
  width: 71%;
}

.col-10-sm {
  width: 79.33%;
}

.col-11-sm {
  width: 87.66%;
}

.col-12-sm {
  width: 96%;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.hidden-sm {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 33.75em) {
  /* 540px */
  .container {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 45em) {
  /* 720px */
  .col-1 {
    width: 4.33%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 12.66%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 21%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 29.33%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 37.66%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 46%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 54.33%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 62.66%;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 71%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 79.33%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 87.66%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 96%;
  }
  .hidden-sm {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 60em) {
  /* 960px */
  .container {
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 60rem;
  }
}

**
/**
    *** custom.css
    **/

.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<div class="sidebar">
  xddd
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color: blue">xd</div>
  <div class="row">
    <code>xDDD hola
      </div>
     </div>
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Eso que agregaste solo son hojas de estilos, como bien comenta @alanfcm, agrega en **un solo** fragmento de código el HTML y el CSS

Comment: @alanfcm Listo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El inconveniente que tienes en grandes resoluciones está dado por un media query que pone esta condición en una clase igual a la que tienes:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 60em) { /* 960px */
  .container {
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 60rem;
  }
}
```

Lo que puedes hacer es sobreescribir esta condición en tu código personalizado:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 60em) { /* 960px */
  .container {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: none;
  }
}
```

También podrías usar otra clase para tu contenedor, con el fin que no interfiera con los estilo propios del framework.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i');

/* UNIVERSAL */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

/* ROOT FONT STYLES */

* {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #333447;
  line-height: 1.5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* TYPOGRAPHY */

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.375rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.font-light {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.font-regular {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.font-heavy {
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* POSITIONING */

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.justify {
  text-align: justify;
}

/* ==== GRID SYSTEM ==== */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.row [class^="col"] {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5rem 2%;
  min-height: 0.125rem;
}

.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4,
.col-5,
.col-6,
.col-7,
.col-8,
.col-9,
.col-10,
.col-11,
.col-12 {
  width: 96%;
}

.col-1-sm {
  width: 4.33%;
}

.col-2-sm {
  width: 12.66%;
}

.col-3-sm {
  width: 21%;
}

.col-4-sm {
  width: 29.33%;
}

.col-5-sm {
  width: 37.66%;
}

.col-6-sm {
  width: 46%;
}

.col-7-sm {
  width: 54.33%;
}

.col-8-sm {
  width: 62.66%;
}

.col-9-sm {
  width: 71%;
}

.col-10-sm {
  width: 79.33%;
}

.col-11-sm {
  width: 87.66%;
}

.col-12-sm {
  width: 96%;
}

.row::after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

.hidden-sm {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 33.75em) {  /* 540px */
  .container {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 45em) {  /* 720px */
  .col-1 {
    width: 4.33%;
  }

  .col-2 {
    width: 12.66%;
  }

  .col-3 {
    width: 21%;
  }

  .col-4 {
    width: 29.33%;
  }

  .col-5 {
    width: 37.66%;
  }

  .col-6 {
    width: 46%;
  }

  .col-7 {
    width: 54.33%;
  }

  .col-8 {
    width: 62.66%;
  }

  .col-9 {
    width: 71%;
  }

  .col-10 {
    width: 79.33%;
  }

  .col-11 {
    width: 87.66%;
  }

  .col-12 {
    width: 96%;
  }

  .hidden-sm {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 60em) { /* 960px */
  .container {
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 60rem;
  }
}

.sidebar{
 width: 20%;
 background-color: blue;
 height: 100%;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 display: inline-block
}
.container{
 background-color: red;
 width: 80%;
 display: inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 60em) { /* 960px */
  .container {
width: 80%;
max-width: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  izquierda
</div>
<div class="container">
    derecha  
</div>
```

Comment: Ahora que me doy cuenta, el problema no es el código en sí, creo que es las dimensiones de la pantalla. No sé si tenga algo que ver, pero cuando le doy a Ampliar, el contenedor deja de ocupar el 80%, es como si ocupara un 50%

Comment: He modificado la respuesta y he planteado un par de soluciones.

Comment: Personalmente, no considero la necesidad de cambiar de clase, porque también se me haría muy incómodo tener 3 divs parents para los childs, pero si lo tendré en cuenta si es que presenta más problemas. No había pensado en los Query de media, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una manera en la que puedes solucionar el problema de las dos columnas:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i');

body, html {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif, arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
}
* {

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Esta es una manera de hacerlo */
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 0.8fr;
  height: 100vh;
  
  /* Puedes limitar la anchura */
  max-width: 1500px;
}

.container__item--sidebar {
  background-color: #0080d4;
  
}
.container__item--content {

  background-color: blue;
}
.container__item--sidebar,
.container__item--content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container">
      <aside class="container__item--sidebar">
        20%
      </aside>
      
      <div class="container__item--content">
        80%
      </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```